# Building ART raw converter on macOS and need help resolving linker errors

Tags: command-line, xcode, development

I downloaded [ART](https://bitbucket.org/agriggio/art/wiki/Home) Raw converter latest release (1.10.1) [source code](https://bitbucket.org/agriggio/art/downloads/) from its project repository on a macOS 11.6.1 mac running mac with these version of Xcode installed:

```
Xcode: 13.1.0.0.1.1633545042
CommandLineTools: 13.0.0.0.1.1630607135
```

(btw: is there a way to keep only the Xcode version so not to have more disk space used?)

I subsequently ran the `cmake` command which successfully generated a makefile checking all the project dependencies, one of which is `exiv2`, which has successfully been configured showing the full `brew` Cellar path.

```shell
$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 13.0.0.13000029
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: Release
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0>=3.16'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.30
-- Checking for module 'gtkmm-3.0>=3.16'
--   Found gtkmm-3.0, version 3.24.5
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0>=2.44'
--   Found glib-2.0, version 2.70.1
-- Checking for module 'glibmm-2.4>=2.44'
--   Found glibmm-2.4, version 2.66.2
-- Checking for module 'cairomm-1.0'
--   Found cairomm-1.0, version 1.14.3
-- Checking for module 'gio-2.0>=2.44'
--   Found gio-2.0, version 2.70.1
-- Checking for module 'giomm-2.4>=2.44'
--   Found giomm-2.4, version 2.66.2
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0>=2.44'
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.70.1
-- Checking for module 'gobject-2.0>=2.44'
--   Found gobject-2.0, version 2.70.1
-- Checking for module 'sigc++-2.0>=2.3.1'
--   Found sigc++-2.0, version 2.10.7
-- Checking for module 'lensfun>=0.2'
--   Found lensfun, version 0.3.95.0
-- Checking for module 'librsvg-2.0>=2.40'
--   Found librsvg-2.0, version 2.50.7
-- Checking for module 'exiv2>=0.24'
--   Found exiv2, version 0.27.5
-- searching for library exiv2 in /usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5/lib
--   result: /usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5/lib/libexiv2.dylib
-- Checking for module 'lcms2>=2.6'
--   Found lcms2, version 2.12
-- Checking for module 'expat>=2.1'
--   Found expat, version 2.2.1
-- Checking for module 'fftw3f'
--   Found fftw3f, version 3.3.10
-- Checking for module 'libtiff-4>=4.0.4'
--   Found libtiff-4, version 4.3.0
-- Found JPEG: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib (found version "90") 
-- Found ZLIB: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib (found version "1.6.37") 
-- Found OpenMP_C: -Xclang -fopenmp (found version "5.0") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xclang -fopenmp (found version "5.0") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "5.0")  
-- Performing Test _fftw3f_multithread
-- Performing Test _fftw3f_multithread - Failed
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:478 (message):
  You are performing an in-source build.  This is discouraged.  For an
  explanation and the advantages of out-of-source builds, please refer to
  http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#What_is_an_.22out-of-source.22_build.3F


-- searching for library lensfun in /usr/local/Cellar/lensfun/0.3.95_4/lib
--   result: /usr/local/Cellar/lensfun/0.3.95_4/lib/liblensfun.dylib
-- Performing Test LENSFUN_HAS_LOAD_DIRECTORY
-- Performing Test LENSFUN_HAS_LOAD_DIRECTORY - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.4/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args`
  (MACINTEGRATION) does not match the name of the calling package
  (MacIntegration).  This can lead to problems in calling code that expects
  `find_package` result variables (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain
  pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/FindMacIntegration.cmake:27 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  rtgui/CMakeLists.txt:177 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found MACINTEGRATION: /usr/local/lib/libgtkmacintegration-gtk3.dylib  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1
```

I then ran `make` to start compiling the project but it stopped after just a few seconds telling me `exiv2` sources are referring to one of brew's exiv2 dependencies libraries `libssh`, currently installed, and the compiler couldn't find libssh header files.

```shell
$ make
[  0%] Creating AboutThisBuild.txt and other version-dependent files
[  0%] Built target UpdateInfo
[  1%] Building CXX object rtengine/CMakeFiles/rtengine.dir/badpixels.cc.o
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/badpixels.cc:23:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/rawimage.h:27:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/dcraw.h:23:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/myfile.h:25:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/rtengine.h:25:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/procparams.h:30:
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1261:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
typedef cmsInt32Number (* cmsSAMPLER16)   (CMSREGISTER const cmsUInt16Number In[],
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1262:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
                                           CMSREGISTER cmsUInt16Number Out[],
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1263:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
                                           CMSREGISTER void * Cargo);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1265:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
typedef cmsInt32Number (* cmsSAMPLERFLOAT)(CMSREGISTER const cmsFloat32Number In[],
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1266:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
                                           CMSREGISTER cmsFloat32Number Out[],
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:1267:44: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++17 [-Wdeprecated-register]
                                           CMSREGISTER void * Cargo);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include/lcms2.h:158:23: note: expanded from macro 'CMSREGISTER'
#  define CMSREGISTER register
                      ^
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/badpixels.cc:24:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/rawimagesource.h:23:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/imagesource.h:29:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/dcp.h:31:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/imagefloat.h:26:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/imageio.h:38:
In file included from /Users/giovanni/Downloads/ART-1.10.1/rtengine/metadata.h:24:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5/include/exiv2/exiv2.hpp:61:
/usr/local/Cellar/exiv2/0.27.5/include/exiv2/ssh.hpp:27:10: fatal error: 'libssh/libssh.h' file not found
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [rtengine/CMakeFiles/rtengine.dir/badpixels.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rtengine/CMakeFiles/rtengine.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I then tried using:

```shell
$ cmake -DSSH_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/opt/libssh/include .
```

But the output was:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    SSH_INCLUDE_DIR
```

So I ended up directly adding to the include files and libraries folders paths to `gcc` as make doesn't seem to be able to find them on its own using:

```shell
$ export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libssh/include:/usr/local/opt/libomp/include:/usr/local/include
$ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libssh/include:/usr/local/opt/libomp/include:/usr/local/include
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/libtiff/lib
```

Now when I run `make` again it goes on compiling the whole project stopping at 48% with a linker error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here is the partial output of the `make` command:

```
$ make                                          
[  0%] Creating AboutThisBuild.txt and other version-dependent files
[  0%] Built target UpdateInfo
[  1%] Building CXX object rtengine/CMakeFiles/rtengine.dir/badpixels.cc.o
```

```
[ 48%] Linking CXX executable ART-cli
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_barrier", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..13 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..18 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..12 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..35 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..16 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..13 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..14 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..15 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_init_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..8 in librtengine.a(dcp.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rtlensfun.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..9 in librtengine.a(rtlensfun.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_init_4u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..74 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(iprgb2out.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(improccoordinator.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..18 in librtengine.a(improccoordinator.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..4 in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_init_8", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(cfa_linedn_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(ahd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rcd_demosaic.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(CA_correct_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(amaze_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..2 in librtengine.a(xtrans_demosaic.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..15 in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_init_8u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..9 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..115 in librtengine.a(dcraw.cc.o)
  "___kmpc_dispatch_next_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..8 in librtengine.a(dcp.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rtlensfun.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..9 in librtengine.a(rtlensfun.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_next_4u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..74 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(iprgb2out.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(improccoordinator.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..18 in librtengine.a(improccoordinator.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..4 in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(pixelshift.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_next_8", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(cfa_linedn_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(ahd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rcd_demosaic.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(CA_correct_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(amaze_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..2 in librtengine.a(xtrans_demosaic.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..15 in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_dispatch_next_8u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..9 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..115 in librtengine.a(dcraw.cc.o)
  "___kmpc_end_critical", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..16 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..13 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..14 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..15 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_reduce", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(PF_correct_RT.cc.o)
  "___kmpc_end_reduce_nowait", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..77 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(green_equil_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..16 in librtengine.a(filmnegativeproc.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_serialized_parallel", referenced from:
      rtengine::init(rtengine::Settings const*, Glib::ustring, Glib::ustring, bool) in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::multiply(float, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::setMode(rtengine::Imagefloat::Mode, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_xyz(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_yuv(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_lab(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::xyz_to_rgb(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_end_single", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..12 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussianBlurImpl<float>(float**, float**, int, int, double, float*, eGaussType, float**) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void rtengine::boxblur<float, float>(float**, float**, float*, int, int, int, int) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVertical3<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussHorizontalSse<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVerticalSsemult<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVerticalSsediv<float>(float**, float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_fini", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(simpleprocess.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(dcp.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..2 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..4 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(simpleprocess.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(dcp.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..2 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..4 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..16 in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..5 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..12 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..13 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..14 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..15 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_8u", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..8 in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..8 in librtengine.a(perspectivecorrection.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..7 in librtengine.a(rawimage.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..8 in librtengine.a(rawimage.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      rtengine::(anonymous namespace)::ImageProcessor::stage_finish(bool) in librtengine.a(simpleprocess.cc.o)
      rtengine::init(rtengine::Settings const*, Glib::ustring, Glib::ustring, bool) in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      rtengine::DCPProfile::apply(rtengine::Imagefloat*, int, Glib::ustring const&, rtengine::ColorTemp const&, std::__1::array<double, 3ul> const&, std::__1::array<std::__1::array<double, 3ul>, 3ul> const&, bool, bool) const in librtengine.a(dcp.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::multiply(float, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::setMode(rtengine::Imagefloat::Mode, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_xyz(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_yuv(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_global_thread_num", referenced from:
      rtengine::init(rtengine::Settings const*, Glib::ustring, Glib::ustring, bool) in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::multiply(float, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::setMode(rtengine::Imagefloat::Mode, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_xyz(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_yuv(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_lab(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::xyz_to_rgb(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_push_num_threads", referenced from:
      rtengine::RawImageSource::getRAWHistogram(LUT<unsigned int>&, LUT<unsigned int>&, LUT<unsigned int>&) in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      rtengine::ImProcFunctions::firstAnalysis(rtengine::Imagefloat const*, rtengine::procparams::ProcParams const&, LUT<unsigned int>&) in librtengine.a(improcfun.cc.o)
      void rtengine::wavelet_level<float>::decompose_level<float>(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int) in librtengine.a(ipdenoise.cc.o)
      rtengine::findMinMaxPercentile(float const*, unsigned long, float, float&, float, float&, bool) in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      void rtengine::wavelet_level<float>::decompose_level<float>(float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int) in librtengine.a(iplocalcontrast.cc.o)
      rtengine::wavelet_level<float>::SynthesisFilterSubsampHorizontal(float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, int, int, int, int, int) in librtengine.a(iplocalcontrast.cc.o)
      rtengine::wavelet_level<float>::SynthesisFilterSubsampVertical(float*, float*, float*, float (*) [4], float (*) [4], int, int, int, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(iplocalcontrast.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_reduce", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(PF_correct_RT.cc.o)
  "___kmpc_reduce_nowait", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..77 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(green_equil_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(hilite_recon.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..16 in librtengine.a(filmnegativeproc.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_serialized_parallel", referenced from:
      rtengine::init(rtengine::Settings const*, Glib::ustring, Glib::ustring, bool) in librtengine.a(init.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::multiply(float, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::setMode(rtengine::Imagefloat::Mode, bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_xyz(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_yuv(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::rgb_to_lab(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      rtengine::Imagefloat::xyz_to_rgb(bool) in librtengine.a(imagefloat.cc.o)
      ...
  "___kmpc_single", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..12 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussianBlurImpl<float>(float**, float**, int, int, double, float*, eGaussType, float**) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void rtengine::boxblur<float, float>(float**, float**, float*, int, int, int, int) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVertical3<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussHorizontalSse<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVerticalSsemult<float>(float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      void (anonymous namespace)::gaussVerticalSsediv<float>(float**, float**, float**, int, int, float) in librtengine.a(gauss.cc.o)
      ...
  "_omp_get_max_threads", referenced from:
      rtengine::RawImageSource::getRAWHistogram(LUT<unsigned int>&, LUT<unsigned int>&, LUT<unsigned int>&) in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      rtengine::ImProcFunctions::firstAnalysis(rtengine::Imagefloat const*, rtengine::procparams::ProcParams const&, LUT<unsigned int>&) in librtengine.a(improcfun.cc.o)
      rtengine::findMinMaxPercentile(float const*, unsigned long, float, float&, float, float&, bool) in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      rtengine::convolution(rtengine::array2D<float> const&, rtengine::Imagefloat const*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, bool) in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      rtengine::convolution(rtengine::array2D<float> const&, rtengine::array2D<float> const&, rtengine::array2D<float>&, bool) in librtengine.a(rt_algo.cc.o)
      rtengine::ImProcFunctions::dynamicRangeCompression(rtengine::Imagefloat*) in librtengine.a(tmo_fattal02.cc.o)
      rtengine::denoise::RGB_denoise(rtengine::ImProcData&, int, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, float*, float*, float*, bool, rtengine::procparams::DenoiseParams const&, double, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, float&, float&) in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
      ...
  "_omp_get_nested", referenced from:
      rtengine::denoise::RGB_denoise(rtengine::ImProcData&, int, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, float*, float*, float*, bool, rtengine::procparams::DenoiseParams const&, double, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, float&, float&) in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
  "_omp_get_num_procs", referenced from:
      Options::setDefaults() in options.cc.o
  "_omp_get_num_threads", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(hphd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(hphd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined..17 in librtengine.a(rawimagesource.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..6 in librtengine.a(demosaic_algos.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined. in librtengine.a(hphd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..1 in librtengine.a(hphd_demosaic_RT.cc.o)
      rtengine::denoise::detail_recovery(int, int, rtengine::LabImage*, rtengine::array2D<float>*, int, int, int, float**, float**, unsigned long, float, int, rtengine::array2D<float>&, rtengine::array2D<float>&, fftwf_plan_s**, fftwf_plan_s**, int, double, bool) in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
      _.omp_outlined..3 in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
  "_omp_set_nested", referenced from:
      rtengine::denoise::RGB_denoise(rtengine::ImProcData&, int, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, rtengine::Imagefloat*, float*, float*, float*, bool, rtengine::procparams::DenoiseParams const&, double, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, rtengine::NoiseCurve const&, float&, float&) in librtengine.a(FTblockDN.cc.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [rtgui/ART-cli] Error 1
make[1]: *** [rtgui/CMakeFiles/rth-cli.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there a guide to successfully compile this software on macOS?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're wanting to build this yourself rather than just use RawTherapee, Gimp etc, or even gods forbid, the *free* image editor your camera manufacturer makes - which at least doesn't have to *guess* at the camera settings like *all* the others have to, including Photoshop. Personally, I wouldn't dream of opening RAWs in anything other than [in my case Nikon's] app first, before I move onto any other image editor.

Comment: Super details. I removed some chitchat and left one question at the end. Worst case someone gives you some guides on this. Best case, someone points to reproducing your issue and relays their solution to modify the code or the setup to compile. I love that you’re hoping to DIY this